# Regular expression: finding two elements not surrounding another element in text

Tags: regex

I need to find badly formatted HTML content from some text; we let users add `strong` and `em` tags but they don't always close them correctly

```
This is some <b>correct</b> formatting
This is some <b>incorrect<b> formatting
```

I would like to catch instances where the formatting is incorrect, ie where an opening tag is not followed by a closing tag. I started using negative lookaheads but have had not much success so far

```
<b>(?!.*?<\/b>.*?)<b>
```

- `<b>` Get opening tag
- `(?!` negative lookahead for

  - `.*?` anything, but not greedily
  - `<\/b>` the closing tag
  - `.*?` anything, but not greedily
- `)` closing the lookahead
- `<b>` Another opening tag

Any idea how I could do that?

**Addendum**: I know about Tony the pony, but I feel it is not coming right now. This problem could be replaced by "I want to find two occurences of a word "zoinx" where there is no occurence of the word "palantir" in between" which is not HTML-related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<b>(?:(?!<\/b>).)*<b>
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/19

For a generalized  version use

```
<([^>]*)>(?:(?!<\/\1>).)*<\1>
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/24

Comment: It does look like it works (trying it out on my test data), but I don't get it: why is the non-capturing group necessary?

Comment: @samy it is not absolutely necessary..Its just that we dont want groups here

Comment: more generalized:
`<(\w+\d?)>(?:(?!<\/\1>).)*<\1>`
for not only capturing `<b>`, but any html tag (without attributes)

Comment: Thanks vks. Your generalized version doesn't work for other tags (<i> and </i> for example); jp-pee's works, though

Comment: Bravo for the general version, this is really interesting to me since I will catch multiple problems in one go

Comment: @samy https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/25 use this if some tags have attributes as well